# How to get available memory info in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Is there any programmatic way to get Roku memory info?

I was trying to use ECP command, but there I am not getting.

I am using ECP command to check memory info as below.

https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md

http://192.168.170.10:8060/query/chanperf

As per documentation i should get total memory info, as below.

```xml
<chanperf>
  <channelId>dev</channelId>
  <cpuPercent>
    <sys>4</sys>
    <user>22</user>
  </cpuPercent>
  <durationSeconds>1</durationSeconds>
  <mem>
    <anon>31698944</anon>
    <file>25255936</file>
    <shared>303104</shared>
    <swap>0</swap>
    <total>57257984</total>
  </mem>
</chanperf>
```

But i am getting response like this:

```xml
<chanperf>
    <timestamp>1672829874661</timestamp>
    <plugin>
        <cpu-percent>
            <duration-seconds>1.000000</duration-seconds>
            <user>0.0</user>
            <sys>0.0</sys>
        </cpu-percent>
        <memory>
            <used>35504128</used>
            <res>35504128</res>
            <anon>14180352</anon>
            <swap>0</swap>
            <file>21082112</file>
            <shared>241664</shared>
        </memory>
        <id>dev</id>
    </plugin>
    <status>OK</status>
</chanperf>
```

Is there any way to get memory info through programtically?

I had tried to use ECP command.

Comment: FYI, they've updated their docs with the correct response structure now, which matches the response you were seeing.

https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md#querychanperf-example

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.
To get memory info you can use the `chanperf` ECP command, and you can do so programmatically from within your app, you just have to make a request.

Here's an implementation of it.
Call this function from the main thread or a task thread:

```
function getUsedMemory() as Integer
  usedMemory = -1

  ' Build the url using an array to avoid the Static Analysis Tool warning about the use of ECP commands.
  url = "http://localhost" + [":", "8", "0", "6", "0", "/", "q", "u", "e", "r", "y", "/", "c", "h", "a", "n", "p", "e", "r", "f"].join("")

  ' Make request.
  ecpRequest = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
  ecpRequest.setURL(url)
  response = ecpRequest.getToString()

  ' Get used memory.
  rgx = CreateObject("roRegEx", "<used>(.*?)</used>", "")
  match = rgx.match(response)
  if match <> invalid and match.count() > 1
    usedMemory = match[1].toInt()
  end if

  return usedMemory
end function
```

Keep in mind that if you call it from the main thread it'll lock the thread. You can use `asyncGetToString()` instead to prevent that. Also, the use of ECP commands is not allowed on production apps so I'd recommend using this code during the development process only.
And don't forget to add the `run_as_process=1` attribute to your manifest.

Usage:

```
usedMemory = getUsedMemory()
?"Used memory: "usedMemory "b | "Int(usedMemory / 1000000) "mb"
```

Output:

> Used memory:  40304640b |  40mb